# If $\zeta= e^{2\pi i/7}$ then $2\cos(2\pi/7) = (\zeta+ \zeta^6)$. Find a cubic polynomial satisfied by $\zeta + \zeta^6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-polynomials

My approach was to set $\zeta + \zeta^6 = a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3$ and then solve for the constants.

I know there is a better way to solve this using the cyclotomic polynomials, but I don't understand how to do that. If anyone is willing to explain I would appreciate it.

Comment: That's not what you want to do. Letting $\alpha=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$, you want an equation of the form $\alpha^3=A\alpha^2+B\alpha+C$. Note that $\alpha^2=\zeta^2+\zeta^{-2}+2$, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that $\zeta^7=1$, so $\zeta$ is a root of $X^6+X^5+X^4+X^3+X^2+1$. Moreover $\zeta^6=\zeta^{-1}$. Consider
$$
\zeta^6+\zeta^5+\zeta^4+\zeta^3+\zeta^2+\zeta+1=0
$$
and divide by $\zeta^3$:
$$
\zeta^3+\frac{1}{\zeta^3}+\zeta^2+\frac{1}{\zeta^2}+\zeta+\frac{1}{\zeta}+1=0
$$
Observe that
$$
x^3+y^3=(x+y)^3-3xy(x+y)
$$
and
$$
x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy
$$
Use with $x=\zeta$ and $y=\zeta^{-1}$.

> $\left(\zeta+\dfrac{1}{\zeta}\right)^3-3\left(\zeta+\dfrac{1}{\zeta}\right)+\left(\zeta+\dfrac{1}{\zeta}\right)^2-2+\left(\zeta+\dfrac{1}{\zeta}\right)+1=0$

Comment: I do not follow from step  two to step three, are you still using the previous equation but transferring the other terms to the other side?

Comment: @confused I just reordered the terms after dividing by $\zeta^3$.

Comment: Okay, so ultimately I'm trying to find $\zeta^{-1}$, correct? Then I'll have the root that is $\zeta^6 + \zeta$. Once I have the root how do I find the cubic polynomial?

Comment: @confused No, you have to find a polynomial $aX^3+bX^2+cX+d$ that has $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}=\zeta+\zeta^6$ as root.

Comment: Yes, that's what I just said. Your last two equations form a system that can be used to find $\zeta^{-1}$ and that will give me the root I need, since $\zeta^{-1} = \zeta^6$. How do I find the cubic corresponding to that root?

Comment: @confused No, you don't have to find $\zeta^{-1}$. Just use the hint (or look at the spoiler).

Comment: Ohhhh. Okay. Is that the final answer then? My issue is that I don't understand how to take the root and find the cubic polynomial.

Comment: $X^3+X^2-2X-1$, that's all!

Comment: Lol, I just realized this myself. This was the worst chapter for me and I did not understand cyclotomic polynomials AT ALL. Thank you so much!

Comment: @egreg This is probably a trivial question but why exactly is $\zeta$ a root of $X^6 + X^5 + X^4 + X^3 + X^2 +X +1$?

Comment: @MathWolf $X^7-1=(X-1)(X^6 + X^5 + X^4 + X^3 + X^2 +X +1)$; since $\zeta^7-1=0$ and $\zeta\ne1$ it must be a root of the second factor.

Answer (score 3):

I do it by a method that’s the same as that of @egreg, but arranged differently.
First I write out
$$
0=\zeta^3+\zeta^2+\zeta+1+\zeta^{-1}+\zeta^{-2}+\zeta^{-3}\,.
$$
Then I write $\xi=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ and write out
$$
\xi^3=\zeta^3+3\zeta+3\zeta^{-1}+\zeta^{-3}\,,
$$
and subtract zero (from the first display) from it, to get the equation
$$
\xi^3=-\zeta^2+2\zeta-1+2\zeta^{-1}-\zeta^{-2}\,,
$$
and this is an obvious linear combination of $\xi^2$, $\xi$, and $1$.